# GoogleTest Mock C++ singleton

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to find out the best/preferred way of mocking a singleton object.

I have a class Singleton here.

```
class Singleton {

public:

static std::shared_ptr<Singleton> getInstance() {
    static std::shared_ptr<Singleton> instance =
            std::make_shared<Singleton>(); // Guaranteed to be destroyed.
    // Instantiated on first use.
    return instance;
}

Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;
Singleton(Singleton &&) = delete;
Singleton& operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;
Singleton& operator=(Singleton &&) = delete;
~Singleton();

void flush();

}
```

with a Foo class calling the singleton at some point...

```
#include <Foo.h>
#include <Singleton.h>

void Foo::action(int value) {

    if (value > 1) {
        Singleton::getInstance()->flush();
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

I would like to mock the Singleton object have the follow FooTest to make sure the flush method is called.

```
TEST_F(FooTest, testFlushIsCalled) {
    auto foo = Foo();
    foo.someAction(2);
    EXPECT_CALL(Singleton::getInstance(), flush()).Times(1);
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singletons are **very** troublesome to mock (and a pain in unit testing in general).

If you can replace the singleton call with dependency injection you will relieve lots of pain and can use standard methods to mock it, i.e.

```
Foo::Foo(Singleton* flushSingleton) : myFlushSingletion(flushSingleton) {};

void Foo::action(int value) {
    if (value > 1) {
        myFlushSingletion->flush();
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Failing that you may be able to use darker magic - but do so at your own peril...
You might turn the (local static) Singleton instance into a protected static variable (and its functions virtual)

```
class Singleton {
//...
protected:
static std::shared_ptr<Singleton> mySingletonInstance;
//...
}
```

Then you can derive a MockSingleton which places itself in the `mySingletonInstance` of the real Singleton - but as I said... better refactor your code, you will be happier in the future.

Comment: Hi, a side question with a problem i ran into, I've mocked the Singleton method, however, the EXPECT_CALL seems to always pass, even without calling it. Any ideas on why that could happen?

Comment: @Dillon Without looking at the source code, hard to say. Remember that you can Debug module tests through (at least in Visual Studio, using the google test adapter), so you may be able set a breakpoint in the mocked function and see where the call comes from. This is the issue with Singletons: Some unrelated part of your code might instantiate it (without you realizing) and suddendly you get unexpected effects.